# How to setUp environment in eclipse to create VoltDB Stored Procedure?

Tags: java, voltdb

I have read about VoltDB and its stored procedure(java) from its website(quick good documentation).

I want to create java Stored Procedure and started with jar (voltdbclient-7.7.jar from maven) but there are some files missing to compile the stored procedure.

Below files not found from JAR.
 - VoltProcedure
 - VoltAbortException
 - SQLStmt etc

I have tried with github source code too. but no luck.

Is there any additional JAR available to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there are two ways to get the voltdb-7.7.jar file:

1. Download the install kit from voltdb.com (untar to install, it will be under the voltdb-ent-7.7/voltdb directory)
2. Compile from source. See instructions at: https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/wiki/Building-VoltDB

However you get the jar file, here are instructions for compiling, packaging, and loading stored procedures: https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/designappprocinstall.php#designappprocpackage

You may also be interested in this how-to instruction on using Eclipse to develop, unit test, and debug stored procedures and java clients: https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/blob/master/examples/HOWTOs/EclipseUnitTestDebug.md

Disclaimer: I work for VoltDB.

Comment: BTW, we are considering adding the voltdb.x.x.jar file to the maven central repository along with the client.